# how to use a reusable workflow in a different site collectoin

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, feature-activation, workflow2013, reusable-workflow

I have create a 2010 workflow in SharePoint designer 2013
I have globally published a workflow and it appears now in my site collection at root site and every sub site in it.
I want to deploy this workflow to test environment that is on different site collection. how do i do that?
The save as template is disabled.
I made a copy of it and it appears in reusable workflow and the save as template is enabled now. i saved it as template, uploaded it in target site collection and activated the feature. it does not show up in the workflow list when i try to add it. Please suggest any stable method to deploy it so that in future also, whenever there is a new workflow or a change to an existing workflow i can move it to different environments easily.

Answer (score 0):

The content type that was used during the creation of the original reusable workflow must also be available within your test environment. Specifically, the same content type must be available within the list/library that will contain the reusable workflow.

Comment: Thanks James for writing. I took a copy of Approval 2010 workflow available in the designer and modified it as per my requirements. I did not select any specific content type. While creating the copy i gave the name and selected All( which was selected default). Now how do i check for content type or fix this issue.

Comment: In your original site collection, navigate to the list/library that contains the reusable workflow.  On the ribbon, under Library (or List) Tools, click the Library (or List) tab. In the Settings group, click Library (or List) settings. Under Content Types, verify the name of the content type (this is the one you will need in the test site collection Library (or List). If Content Types does not appear, click Advanced settings, and click Yes under "Allow management of content types?", and then click OK.

Comment: So do you mean i go to my source site and from the library where i have my workflow associated, check the related content type in it and get the same in destination site?

Comment: Correct, you will need the same content type in both locations. You can recreate the content type manually (same name, same columns) in the Test site collection.

Comment: well, nothing helped with the 2010 approval workflow

Comment: Have you tried creating a new site collection within your own environment (not test) and deployed the reusable workflow? If it doesn't work, that may help us isolate the issue.